# mysql After insert trigger on table 1 that insert in table 2 that have an after insrt trigger that updates table 1

Tags: mysql, recursion, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have two tables one called **fs_note** the other called **dumy_fs_note** 
I created after Insert and after Delete triggers on the **fs_table** that insert a row with calculated data to the **dumy_fs_table** that has an after insert trigger that should update a certain row in fs_table with the new values 
The problem is that now i am having error: 
`#1442 Can't update table 'fs_note' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` 
why is that?? it is the dumy_fs_note table that is trying to update the fs_table not the same table, Any idea what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you just can't do that. Mysql is this way preventing circular loops and memory issues... It is like updating a cursor being parsed: some engines allow it, others no.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, I just needed to be sure that this is not possible, you saved me from going crazy :)